# Amortization Schedule in Excel - Know how much interest will be saved by large payment

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a really nice Amortization Schedule built in Excel using the steps from this page: http://www.wikihow.com/Prepare-Amortization-Schedule-in-Excel

It works really nicely, but I am planning to make some large payments and I would love to calculate how much interest I will save, over the life of the loan, for making these larger payment.

E.g., if I pay $10k for one payment I will save $4000 in interest over the life of the loan, etc.

**Is there a way to calculate this?**

Comment: For that particular spreadsheet, you can just type in column C the new payment amount, replacing the cell reference, and the changes should show throughout.  If you're just looking to do the math, that's a different issue . . .

Comment: No, I know that I can just enter the 10,000 value into the payment column for a certain date and it will recalculate things. I just want to calculate out how much I am saving in interest for the life of the loan for doing that.

Answer (score 1):

The CUMIPMT formula in Excel will calculate total interest that should be paid over the course of a loan. Then you could subtract what you are paying based on your table and get the amount you are saving.

Here is the formula you will need to use to calculate total interest that should be paid (based on using the same spreadsheet you referenced)

```
=-CUMIPMT(B4/12,B3,B1,1,B3,0)
```

You should also change a few formulas in your table to make sure you never go negative in your table.

Change the formula in C8 (then copy down) to:

```
=MIN($B$4,H7+(B8*($B$2/12)))
```

Then you can subtract total interest actually paid from the calculated interest that should have been paid to come up with savings.